# Performance differences in run-time polymorphism between C and C++

Tags: c++, c, benchmarking, run-time-polymorphism

I know benchmarking is a very delicate subject and simple, not-well-thought-out benchmarks are mostly meaningless for performance comparisons, but what I have right now is actually a pretty small and contrived example that I think should be easily explainable. So, even if the question seems unhelpful, it would at least help me in understanding benchmarking.

So, here I go.

I was trying to experiment with simple API design in C, using run-time polymorphism kind of behaviour via `void *`. Then I compared it with same thing implemented in C++ using regular virtual functions. Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int dummy_computation()
{
    return 64 / 8;
}

/* animal library, everything is prefixed with al for namespacing */
#define AL_SUCCESS 0;
#define AL_UNKNOWN_ANIMAL 1;
#define AL_IS_TYPE_OF(animal, type) \
    strcmp(((type *)animal)->animal_type, #type) == 0\

typedef struct {
    const char* animal_type;
    const char* name;
    const char* sound;
} al_dog;

inline int make_dog(al_dog** d) {
    *d = (al_dog*) malloc(sizeof(al_dog));
    (*d)->animal_type = "al_dog";
    (*d)->name = "leslie";
    (*d)->sound = "bark";
    return AL_SUCCESS;
}

inline int free_dog(al_dog* d) {
    free(d);
    return AL_SUCCESS;
}
    
typedef struct {
    const char* animal_type;
    const char* name;
    const char* sound;
} al_cat;

inline int make_cat(al_cat** c) {
    *c = (al_cat*) malloc(sizeof(al_cat));
    (*c)->animal_type = "al_cat";
    (*c)->name = "garfield";
    (*c)->sound = "meow";
    return AL_SUCCESS;
}

inline int free_cat(al_cat* c) {
    free(c);
    return AL_SUCCESS;
}

int make_sound(void* animal) {
    if(AL_IS_TYPE_OF(animal, al_cat)) {
        al_cat *c = (al_cat*) animal;
        return dummy_computation();
    } else if(AL_IS_TYPE_OF(animal, al_dog)) {
        al_dog *d = (al_dog*) animal;
        return dummy_computation();
    } else {
        printf("unknown animal\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
/* c style library finishes here */

/* cpp library with OOP */
struct animal {
    animal(const char* n, const char* s) 
    :name(n)
    ,sound(s)
    {} 
    virtual int make_sound() {
        return dummy_computation();
    }
    const char* name;
    const char* sound;
};

struct cat : animal {
    cat() 
    :animal("garfield", "meow")
    {}
};

struct dog : animal {
    dog() 
    :animal("leslie", "bark")
    {}
};
/* cpp library finishes here */
```

I have something called `dummy_computation`, just to make sure I get some computational thingy going on in the benchmark. I would normally implement different `printf` calls for barking, meowing etc. for such an example but `printf` is not easily benchmarkable in quick-benchmarks.com. The actual thing I want to benchmark is run-time polymorphism implementation. So that's why I chose to make some small function and used it in both C and C++ implementation as a filler.

Now, in quick-benchmarks.com, I have a benchmark like following:

```
static void c_style(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    al_dog* d = NULL;
    al_cat* c = NULL;

    make_dog(&d);
    make_cat(&c);
    
    int i1 = make_sound(d);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(i1);
    int i2 = make_sound(c);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(i2);

    free_dog(d);
    free_cat(c);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(c_style);

static void cpp_style(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    animal* a1 = new dog();
    animal* a2 = new cat();
    int i1 = a1->make_sound();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(i1);
    int i2 = a2->make_sound();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(i2);
    delete a1;
    delete a2;
  }
}
BENCHMARK(cpp_style);
```

I added `DoNotOptimize` calls so that *virtual* calls would not end up being optimized-out.

Whole benchmark can be found here, if recreating it seems painful.

https://quick-bench.com/q/ezul9hDXTjfSWijCfd2LMUUEH1I

Now, to my surprise, C version comes out 27 times faster in the results. I expected maybe some performance hits on C++ version because it is a more refined solution but definitely not 27-fold.

Can someone explain these results? Do virtual function calls really incur this much overhead compared to C? Or is it the way I set up this benchmarking experiment that is completely meaningless? If so, how would one more correctly benchmark such issues?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the cost of `malloc`/`new` dominates the execution time

Comment: Good chances are, you are benchmarking C vs C++ allocators.

Comment: But does `new` performs ~27-fold worse than `malloc`? Even that I was not expecting.

Comment: as a matter of fact, if you look at the assembly view on the link he posted, it shows just that. A large part of the time is around the call to new

Comment: C version doesn't do function ptrs, it does `if`-`else` branching with a small set of types.

Comment: Your C code doesn't do a "virtual call"; it always calls a statically-determined function. Change it so it selects a function at runtime.

Comment: It is unlikely that this test is measuring C++ polymorphism.  If the compiler can see `a1 = new dog();` and `a1->make_sound();` in the same scope, it should _devirtualize_ the function call and directly call the correct `make_sound` function.  vtable lookup isn't necessary.

Comment: The C version has `malloc` optimized out as far as I can tell.  The C++ version fails to optimize out `new`.  So the one that does dynamic allocation takes longer.  Not surprising.  The implementation differences -- one using function pointers the other comparing strings -- would easily explain the optimization differences.

Comment: `dummy_computation()` does not do any computation. It is calculated at compile time and inlined. I have also put the whole code to godbolt.org (removing the benchmark part), and `c_style()` becomes a no-op. The compiler is able to detect that the code does not have side effects and eliminates it. Also, `AL_IS_TYPE_OF()` looks pretty UB-ish to me.

Comment: @Kane I definitely want an explanation of better way to do such *polymorphism* in C, with closed set of types etc. I am pretty sure the way I did with `AL_IS_TYPE_OF()`is not the best practice. It just gave the correct results on the compiler I tried so I kept it. Did not mention my doubts about it in the question because then it would mean two questions in one. But I am open to be pointed to good resources on the subject.

Comment: @meguli> for C polymorphism you would make a struct of function pointers, say `struct animal_operations`, and have a pointer to it in your instance. `make_*` functions would set the pointer to the correct operations table (basically, reimplementing a vtable). You would then  `animal->op->make_sound(animal)`.

Comment: @spectras> But even for a closed set of types like this? I hoped there would be a solution essentially similar to this a la if-else chains or case-switch such that I can avoid function pointers. Yeah, in that case it is not really polymorphism, I know, But is my implementation against best practices even for closed set of types? Is the C approach to such a problem just ad-hoc override for each type in the closed set, like `make_sound_cat`, `make_sound_dog`...

Comment: Your implementation is fine (except for the small glitch in AL_IS_TYPE_OF, which just needs be fixed, but that does not affect the overall design). It's just not polymorphism :)

Comment: @spectras Ok, while we are at it then :) what is the problem with that macro?

Comment: @meguli> in c++ you cannot cast a `al_cat*` to an `al_dog*` and use the pointer, that has undefined behavior. The common solution to that for c/c++ compatible code is to create a base struct, say, `al_animal` that you put as first member of `al_cat` and `al_dog`.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you're not implementing the same thing. If you do an `if`-chain of `switch`-chain in C, then you have (mathematically) a discriminated union, which is `std::variant` in C++.

If you'd like the C++ version to be ported to C, then you need function pointers. It'll very likely be equally slow. The reason behind, `virtual` means forward compatible: any code, including a library loaded later, can descend from your base and implement the `virtual` methods. It means, sometimes you don't even know at compile-time of your base module what (descendant) classes it might need to handle (the type system is open). Such forward compatibility is not provided for `std::variant`, which is closed (limited to a fixed list of types).

Comment: That makes sense, I was expecting some differences going in since virtual functions do much more.  I will definitely try the `variant` version as well. The thing I want to actually get out this experiment was, most of the time I have a closed set of types but I am still using virtual functions out of habit. I wanted to see how a hand-rolled solution would perform in such cases. Ie. just to make me convince when I truly need `virtual`.

Comment: @meguli> when you have a closed set of types and you don't care of keeping it open to addition, inheritance is the wrong tool for the job, so you are right to question habits. I wish more people did, I still often see inheritance hierarchies being created for no good reason in new code.

Comment: @spectras "inheritance is the wrong tool for the job" you assume that execution speed is most valuable result of a program. It is quite often (I would say most of the time) not. If code with inheritance is easier to read and implement, which is subjective of course, it may be preferable tool than faster but more complicated approach.

Comment: And I can confirm that comparing it to a solution using C++ variants indeed gives almost the same results. @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont explained above that in the case of inheritance I shared above, compiler is not able to optimize calls to `new`. I guess in the case of `variant`, it is on the stack and even if there is allocation, I am assuming it is done in-place, ie. it can optimize allocations when using variants.

Comment: @spectras Exactly, wisdom spoken here. (Idk how many times I mentioned this in the past during coding.)

Comment: @Slava It's not only speed, it's also verifiability & testability. For a closed hierarchy, you can write proper tests: test each of them. You might ignore some combinations e.g. when it's N x N x N, but you're aware of what you ignore. For an open hierarchy, it's very difficult.

Comment: But I don't think a solution using variants is less-readable, at least feels as much pleasant to me if not more. So I kinda get the sentiment; use variants if you have closed set of types and not inheritance in such cases.

Comment: Easy is subjective indeed. Inheritance has a lot of design complexity, because is-a relationship often does not really match what is being modeled, and has lots of pitfalls (the canonical example Square is-a Rectangle design failure comes to mind). It also leads to creating arbitrary relationships for technical reasons that pollute the design.

Comment: "But I don't think a solution using variants is less-readable" it is subjective and matter of experience. If a particular developer(s) have more experience designing with inheritance it would more simpler for them and code is more readable. And complicated long errors that template metaprogramming produce does not help here. Hope concepts will improve that situation though. Anyway, right tool is not only matter on how good it is by itself but how familiar particular developer is with it.